# Регулярное выражение для цен

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как создать подходящее регулярное выражение?
Есть такие строки:

```
text    16.11 19.22 21.33
text    17.11 23.22 25.33 27.55
text    18.11 26.22
```

нужно чтобы получилось так:

```
array('test'=>'text', 'prices'=>[16.11, 19.22, 21.33]);
array('test'=>'text', 'prices'=>[17.11, 23.22, 25.33, 27.55]);
array('test'=>'text', 'prices'=>[18.11, 26.22]);
```

создал что-то похожее, но не совсем подходит:

```
\$arr[]=array('test'=>'$1','prices'=>[$2]);
```

Как правильно создать регулярное выражение?
Количество цен может быть разное в ряду

**P.S.**

```
([a-zA-Z]*)\s*(([0-9\.]+))+  
=> array('test'=>'$1','prices'=>[$2])\s
```

получается так:

```
array('test'=>'text','prices'=>[16.11])sarray('test'=>'','prices'=>[19.22])sarray('test'=>'','prices'=>[21.33])s
array('test'=>'text','prices'=>[17.11])sarray('test'=>'','prices'=>[23.22])sarray('test'=>'','prices'=>[25.33])sarray('test'=>'','prices'=>[27.55])s
array('test'=>'text','prices'=>[18.11])sarray('test'=>'','prices'=>[26.22])s
```

Comment: Какой инструмент/язык используется? C#? JavaScript?

Comment: @JohnyL, использую php, и это я пытаюсь реализовать в phpstorm, через комбинацию клавиш ctrl+r для замены строк, но это сути не меняет

Comment: проблема то в чем, в запятых? вторую замены нельзя провести что ли?

Comment: Чем вам `explode` не подходит?

Comment: Поддержу @And. У вас по сути есть три разделителя: `PHP_EOL` чтобы разбить по строкам, четыре пробела или таб для того, чтобы разделить строку на текст и цены (тут можно и `preg_split` с регуляркой `\s{4}|\t`, и просто `explode` с четырмя пробелами)  и, наконец, пробел, чтобы разделить цены.

Comment: В два хода: 1) `^text\t([\d.\h]+)$` => `array('test'=>'text', 'prices'=>[$1]);` ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/hJwyCs/1/)), 2)  `(?:\G(?!\A)|'prices'=>\[)[\d.]*\K\h+` => `", "` ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/hJwyCs/2)).

Comment: @And, эти строки просто копируются с другого сайта, копипаст, как в первом примере, т.е. все строки сразу вместе. Можно было бы написать парсер, но это другой вопрос.  Хотелось именно узнать, как можно с помощью регулярки предусмотреть, что в одной строке может быть разное количество цен.

Comment: Ну как написал `Wiktor Stribiżew` в 2 прохода. И какая разница копируется или не копируется. Проходом по массиву полученному через `explode` тоже вариант. И кстати не из худших, а возможно даже и из быстрых.

Comment: @And, кстати в вопросе пропустил своё регулярное выражение, показал только вариант замены, добавил регулярку, но не совсем правильно работает

Comment: @And вы смысла не поняли. автору не надо делать эту замену во время выполнения пхп кода. пхп тут вообще не при чем. У него есть текстовый файл с набором строк, он хочет его преобразовать в файл с исполняемым кодом. Работает автор в пхпшторме. метка пхпх тут используется для обозначения синтаксиса который хотят получить на выходе, а не про выполнение пхп кода и решение задачи с его помощью. Вопрос о функциях поиска и замены текста в текстовом редакторе.

Comment: @teran, да ладно? Правда что-ли? А что-же ответ тогда приняли? И да, для этого есть метка `phpstorm` собственно. Но увы, вы не правы, всетаки используется это через `php`, а работает он в `phpstorm`. Вот и все собственно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "
text    16.11 19.22 21.33
text    17.11 23.22 25.33 27.55
text    18.11 26.22
";
preg_match_all('/^(\D+)([\d+\.\s]+)$/im', $str, $matches);
$res = [];
foreach ($matches[1] as $ix => $key) {
    $res[$ix]['test'] = trim($key);
    $res[$ix]['prices'] = array_map(function($i) {return (float) $i;}, explode(' ', $matches[2][$ix]));
}
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: `array_map('floatval', explode(...))`. Хотя сама по себе операция сомнительна)

Answer (score 0):

Решение с тремя explode [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/f71VD):

```
echo 'Если количество/вид пробелов жёстко заданы/известны:', PHP_EOL;
$res = [];
$lines = explode("\n", trim($str));
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  [$key, $prices] = explode("    ", $line);
  $prices = explode(' ', $prices);
  $res[] = ['key' => $key, 'prices' => $prices];
}
echo json_encode($res), PHP_EOL;
```

Решение с preg_split [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Lt08M):

```
echo 'Если не завязываться на количестве/виде пробелов: ', PHP_EOL;
$res = [];
$lines = preg_split('#[\n\r]+#', trim($str));
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $prices = preg_split('#\s+#', $line);
  $key = array_shift($prices);
  $res[] = ['key' => $key, 'prices' => $prices];
}
echo json_encode($res), PHP_EOL;
```

---

Для генерации кода в PHPStorm, могу предложить вот такую шутку:
`^(\S+)\s+(.*)` => `['key' => '$1', 'prices' => explode(' ', '$2')]`